# How to make React listen to event in Child component first instead of Parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this example

```
<div onClick={() => redirectTo('/foo')}>
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="button" onClick={() => redirectTo('/bar')} />
</div>;
```

when i test this example in this case by click to second input , React always redirect to /foo, is that normal behavior and how can i make React redirect to /bar? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: @about14sheep not really, if input event triggered before div event may be stopPropagation can help!

Comment: the click event is being propagated up the DOM. Not your function

Comment: Another more specific method would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: i don't know why but it always come to div event function first (in this case redirectTo('/foo')) so i can not do stopPropagation. So weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is propagating from the input to the div and both redirects occur. You are seeing the result of the last redirect.

You can stop the propagation of the input's click event.

```
<div onClick={() => redirectTo('/foo')}>
  <input type="text"/>
  <input
    type="button"
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      redirectTo('/bar');
    }}
  />
</div>;
```